# How to find the sum of arrays entered by user?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, function, sum

How do I find the sum of the numbers entered by the user in the `numbersBox`?
If the user entered "5, 3, 6, 1" in the `numbersBox`, I should be getting the answer "15" in the `sumBox` after clicking the "Find Sum" button. I cannot figure out how to add up all the array elements and what should I be putting in the for loop.

```
function findSUM(){
    list = numbersBox.value.split(",");

    var sum = list[0];
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        list[i] = parseInt(list[i]);

        if(list[i] < i){ 
            max += list[i];
        }
    }
    sumBox.value = sum; 
}
```

---

```
<label>Write numbers separated by commas:</label>
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="numbersBox" />

<label>Sum of all numbers:</label>

<input type="text" id="sumBox" />

<button type="button" onclick="findSUM();">Find Sum</button>
```

Thank you. I will really appreciate all your help.

Comment: If its about finding sum, can you explain why do you have this: `if(list[i] < i){ `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to converts all array elements to `Number` here [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) can be used. Iteration should start with 2nd index as variable `sum` is initialized with value if number at first index.

```js
function findSUM() {
  //Create a list of Numbers
  var list = document.getElementById('numbersBox').value
    .split(",")
    .map(function(x) {
      return isNaN(x) ? 0 : Number(x);
    });

  //Init with first no
  var sum = list[0];

  //Iteration starts wit 2nd element
  for (var i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
    sum += list[i];
  }
  document.getElementById('sumBox').value = sum;
}
```

```html
<label>Write numbers separated by commas:</label>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="numbersBox" />
<label>Sum of all numbers:</label>
<input type="text" id="sumBox" />
<button type="button" onclick="findSUM();">Find Sum</button>
```

Comment: `1,2,three` => `NaN`

Comment: Note: Here `sumBox.value` is working because, sumbox is an ID of input. Its a bad practice. You should rather fetch element

Comment: Can you please explain to me what `.map(Number)` is for? Thank you.

Comment: @DiannaRaizelTy, `.map(Number)` can be written as `.map(function(x){ return Number(x)})`. basically it iterates each element and converts it to using `Number` constructor

Answer (score 1):

I think you little over-engineered the loop, simply split the values and add them to sum while traversing through the array.

```js
function findSUM(){
    list = numbersBox.value.split(",");
    console.log(list);
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        sum += !isNaN(list[i]) ? +list[i] : 0 ; // here '+' would cast the string to number
    }
    sumBox.value = sum; 
}
```

```html
<label>Write numbers separated by commas:</label>
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="numbersBox" />

<label>Sum of all numbers:</label>

<input type="text" id="sumBox" />

<button type="button" onclick="findSUM();">Find Sum</button>
```

Comment: You could also check for `NaN` before adding. `sum += !isNaN(list[i])? +list[i] : 0`

Comment: Nice usage of the leading `+`

Answer (score 1):

Use this code..

```
 list = [12,56,9];
 var Total =  list.reduce(function(a,b){
   return a+b;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the sum of numbers in the entered input by the user i.e. `"5, 3, 6, 1"`, you can split the string by `,` and use the `map` function to convert the resulted string array to an integer array and then use the `reduce` function to calculate the sum of the numbers in the integer array by using a simple function which adds two operands.

```js
function findSum() {
  var element = document.getElementById('numbersBox');
  var sumBox = document.getElementById('sumBox');
  var numbers = processInput(element.value);
  var sum = getSum(numbers);
  sumBox.value = sum;
}

function processInput(input) {
  if (typeof input === 'string' || input instanceof String) {
    return input.split(',').map(function(currentValue, index, arr) {
      return !isNaN(currentValue) && currentValue.length ? parseInt(currentValue) : 0;
    });
  }
}

function getSum(numbers) {
  var sum = 0;

  if (numbers instanceof Array) {
    sum = numbers.reduce(add);
    // sum = numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0); // ES 2015
  }

  function add(a, b) {
    return a + b
  }

  return sum;
}
```

```html
<label>Write numbers separated by commas:</label>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="numbersBox" />

<label>Sum of all numbers:</label>

<input type="text" id="sumBox" />

<button type="button" onclick="findSum();">Find Sum</button>
```

The above code has different functions for processing/parsing the data and for calculating the sum, the below example groups all actions into a single function instead of separating the responsibilities.

```js
function findSum() {
  var element = document.getElementById('numbersBox');
  var sumBox = document.getElementById('sumBox');
  var numbers = element.value.split(',');
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    var number = numbers[i];
    sum += !isNaN(number) && number.length ? parseInt(number) : 0;
  }

  sumBox.value = sum;
}
```

```html
<label>Write numbers separated by commas:</label>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="numbersBox" />

<label>Sum of all numbers:</label>

<input type="text" id="sumBox" />

<button type="button" onclick="findSum();">Find Sum</button>
```

Comment: If you are already looping to calculate `sum`, why do you need another loop to parse values to int? Both can be merged

Comment: @Rajesh, you are right, the parsing and summation can be done using a single loop, for e.g. in this way ['5', '3', '6', '1'].reduce(function (a, b) { return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b); }); I'd just isolated parsing and summation as different responsibilities to keep separation, when performance matters the most and when dealing with large data they can be merged into one I think.

Comment: That is not a bad practice, but then its wiser to have different functions like `cleanData` and `processData` or `getSum`. This way your code will be more readable. But if you have only one function, I would suggest avoiding multiple fir loops

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
function findSUM(){
    list = numbersBox.value.split(",");
    var sum = parseInt(list[0]);
    for(var i = 1; i < list.length; i++){
       list[i] = parseInt(list[i]);
       sum += list[i];
    }
    sumBox.value = sum; 
}
```

Comment: Please check previous answers before answering. I'm not demotivating you but if your answer is very similar to someone else, it will not add mush value. Also you should try to explain your attempt. Just giving working code is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

A nice clean solution, that is easy to read and understand, which validates along the way and supports floats rather than just integers.

```js
function findSUM()
{
  var list = document.getElementById("numbersBox").value.split(",");
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++)
    if(list[i]&&!isNaN(list[i]))
      sum += parseFloat(list[i]);
  document.getElementById("sumBox").value = sum;
}
```

```html
<label>Write numbers separated by commas:</label>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="numbersBox" />
<label>Sum of all numbers:</label>
<input type="text" id="sumBox" />
<button type="button" onclick="findSUM();">Find Sum</button>
```